# In the following code i want to show the WHOLE names on x axis nd dont want them to overlap with the legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrvteorw/ . I dont want the series to over lap with x axis. Series should be shifted to the bottom where the x axis string ends.
I want it to look like http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bubble-3d/

```
$(function(){
// Set up the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        type: 'column',

        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text:'hi',
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text:'hfggggggi',
        },
        labels: {
        align:'right',
            autoRotation: [-10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90]
        },

        categories: ['jasdsaa','sdgsd','','','','sdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff','sdddddddddddddddddddddd']
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Chart rotation demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Test options by dragging the sliders below'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25
        }
    },

    series:[{

        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

function showValues() {
    $('#R0-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
    $('#R1-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
}

// Activate the sliders
$('#R0').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});
$('#R1').on('change', function () {
    chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = this.value;
    showValues();
    chart.redraw(false);
});

showValues();
});
```

Comment: Your first JS Fiddle doesn't work (403 Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Legend will be placed like you need it by default if you let Highcharts use `margin` internally calculated instead of setting it to `75`, so remove `margin` option and chart should look as you want it to.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mrvteorw/2/